# Building OpenJDK 9 32-bit on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, cygwin, 32-bit, java

Has anyone tried to build OpenJDK 9 32-bit on Windows? I have pulled the code from the repository http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9. I have also followed the instructions in common\doc\building.html. (Using the latest cygwin with Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.)

The configure step works fine:

```
./configure --with-freetype-src=/cygdrive/d/HG/jdk9/freetype-2.5.3 --with-target-bits=32
```

The configure succeeds with no errors or warnings. The "build\windows-x86-normal-server-release" folder gets created and populated.

```
Configuration summary:
* Debug level:    release
* HS debug level: product
* JDK variant:    normal
* JVM variants:   server
* OpenJDK target: OS: windows, CPU architecture: x86, address length: 32
* Version string: 9-internal+0-adhoc..jdk9 (9-internal)

Tools summary:
* Environment:    cygwin version 2.9.0(0.318/5/3) (root at /cygdrive/c/cygwin64)
* Boot JDK:       java version "9.0.1"  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)   (at /cygdrive/c/Java/jdk-9.0.1)
* Toolchain:      microsoft (Microsoft Visual Studio 2013)
* C Compiler:     Version 18.00.40629 (at /cygdrive/c/progra~2/micros~1.0/vc/bin/cl)
* C++ Compiler:   Version 18.00.40629 (at /cygdrive/c/progra~2/micros~1.0/vc/bin/cl)

Build performance summary:
* Cores to use:   8
* Memory limit:   32672 MB
```

However, the make operation fails, no matter what target I use:

```
$ make clean

/usr/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
make[1]: *** [/cygdrive/d/HG/jdk9/make/Init.gmk:293: main] Error 2
make: *** [/cygdrive/d/HG/jdk9/make/Init.gmk:185: clean] Error 2
```

Any ideas?
thanks,
-Tom

Comment: Hey, @alexkasko, any ideas?